# Need to extract data with xmlpath / xmlsearch

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xml>
  <site>
    <id>123</id>
    <po>BT123</po>
  </site>
  <order>
    <shipping>
      <shippingmethod>1</shippingmethod>
      <firstname>Test</firstname>
      <lastname>User</lastname>
      <address>1234 My Place</address>
      <address2>Apt 101</address2>
      <city>Anytown</city>
      <state>AL</state>
      <zip>12345</zip>
    </shipping>
    <orderitems>
      <item>
        <isbn>9780752419930</isbn>
        <rentalterm>1</rentalterm>
      </item>
      <item>
        <isbn>0495599336</isbn>
        <rentalterm>3</rentalterm>
      </item>
      <item>
        <isbn>0743500210</isbn>
        <rentalterm>2</rentalterm>
      </item>
    </orderitems>
  </order>
</xml>
```

What I want to do is get all the ISBNs where the rental term is not 2
I know how to get ALL the ISBNs:

```
//item/isbn/text()
```

and specific rental terms:

```
//item[rentalterm!=2]
```

But I am not sure how to put them together. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
//item[rentalterm!=2]/isbn/text()
```

assuming all items have a rentalterm child.

Answer (score 3):

Use this expression:

```
//item[not(rentalterm='2')]/isbn/text()
```

In English: *Get the text nodes of any `isbn` element the parent of which is an `item` element not having a `rentalterm` child whose value is equal to `2`*

Contrast with this expression:

```
//item[rentalterm!=2]/isbn/text()
```

...which translates to: *Get the text nodes of any `isbn` element the parent of which is an `item` element having at least one `rentalterm` child whose value is not equal to `2`.*

In other words, this second expression will not match `item` elements that have no `rentalterm` children, but  *will* match `item` elements with multiple `rentalterm` children as long as at least one does not have a string value equal to `2`.

To put it yet another way, the predicate `[not(rentalterm='2')]` can be read as *does not contain a `rentalterm` child whose string value is equal to `2`*, whereas `[rentalterm!=2]` should be read as *contains a `rentalchild` whose string value is not equal to `2`*.

The [spec describes it like this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#Booleans):

> If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string,
>   then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other string is true.

Comment: Is the not() faster than != ?

Comment: It's not a question of speed. `not(rentalterm='2')` returns `true` when the `item` does not contain *any* child `rentalterm` whose value is `2`. One the other hand, `rentalterm!=2` uses existential quantification, which means that if there's *any* `rentalterm` child not equal to `2` then select that `item`, even if there is also another `rentalterm` whose value *is* `2`. Because of this, `not` is almost always more clear (and definitely more strict/safe) than `!=` in XPath. (Unless you  know for a fact that you *meant* to use `!=`; understanding the difference is important.)

Comment: Great comment. Another way to see the difference is that `item[rentalterm != '2']` **is** equal to `item/rentalterm[. != '2']/..` but this **is not** equal to `item[not(rentalterm = '2')]`

Comment: @jasso - Well, they're not equal in the sense that one matches `item` and one matches `rentalterm`, but it's still a helpful point.